# Batch Coding for MS-DOS

Tags: sorting, batch-file, dos

I would like to sort and move files with batch coding, is that possible?

Let's say, I have following files lists in folder :

```
A1.txt
C1.txt
A1.pdf
C1.doc
A1.doc
B1.pdf
B1.txt
C1.pdf
B1.doc
```

When I run the DOS batch file without parameters and coding file name in batch scripting, The batch file will sort the file and create folder according to file name.

"A1.txt A1.pdf A1.doc" should move in folder called A1 which is automatically, likewise, B1 and C1 folder should be created, the files should be moved in their folder.

Comment: You really should clarify if you mean actual DOS or current versions of Windows (You used the DOS tag, but handling .pdf's in DOS is probably pretty rare)

Comment: Jkegami answered correctly. I mentioned about different file extension about to sort and moving only. that doesn't have to do with any type of files though.

Comment: %%~nq is not valid DOS batch syntax, but it is valid on Windows NT/cmd.exe, so next time, don't tag it with DOS unless you actually mean DOS or possibly Win9x

Comment: Did you read title of subject? I think, you are still using Win3 and Win9x. if you can't give answers, pass to another questions dude. don't troll around. I tagged DOS for reason, because I need the DOS syntax. I am not here for argument, I am here for answers and questions.

Comment: @Winthan Aung: If you want DOS syntax, why did you mark a answer that will only work on Windows NT?

Comment: Because It WORKS for me. I am using DOS on Win NT. Does that make sense for you?

Comment: @Winthan Aung: No that does not make sense to me since WinNT's cmd.exe is not DOS. Just because you have a black screen with white text does not mean that you are using DOS!

Comment: Do you know what does cmd.exe stand for. CMD is command interpreter for MS-DOS. Without that file, you would not be able to use the computer. Then I can call DOS commands with it. To give you example, wearing condom at having sex does meant having sex too. It doesn't meant it is not having sex with D***.

Comment: Next time, you read title correctly and think about latest version to give answers if you want to give answers, otherwise go and waste your time at others forums.

Comment: @Winthan Aung: CMD.EXE is a interpreter for batch files, not "interpreter for MS-DOS", MS-DOS is (was) a operating system, batch files != DOS. As far as your title goes, if you really mean DOS then you need to unmark the current answer since it is not DOS compatible, or if you only need this batch file to run on NT4+, rename the question...

Comment: I don't need to care to rename as long as it works for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you actually want a *Windows* batch file,

```
for %%q in (*) do (
   if not exist "%%~nq" md "%%~nq"
   move "%%q" "%%~nq"
)
```

Run "help for" for documentation on "for" and the "~" notation.

(Written for a batch file. If you want to run the command from the prompt, use one "%" instead of two.)

Comment: I really hope he actually does want a true-blue DOS batch file.  I've got a manual on DOS 3.2 around here somewhere that is just begging to be opened again...